# amazon cognito - how to change the redirect_uri?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

Is it not possible to modify the `redirect_uri` of a cognito user pool after creating it?
There is no option in the ui to access this!

Comment: You can modify callback URL's in App Client's settings, not User Pool.
With new Cognito UI navigate to Cognito User Pool > App Integrations, scroll to the bottom > App client list > <your app client> > Hosted UI.

Comment: @szymon omg... Thank you!! If u want to make it an answer I'd accept.

Comment: Please insert it as an answer thanks!